# Why does my HTML page have extra width in IE7?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, width

My HTML page has extra width, but only in IE7. I get horizontal scroll bars even though all the content of the page seems to fit in the browser window.

Take a look:

- Video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_cxGzcTodTk
- HTML page: http://photoshop.faressoft.org/

Comment: Video screenshot! Kudos!

Comment: @Paul D. Waite : thanks for the editing.

Comment: Interesting tidbit: I translated this to English with Google Translate an the problem isn't present. May be a problem with the RTL orientation and other code in the document..?

Comment: No problem. Regarding your problem, I’ve seen it before on pages with a right-to-left design. Maddeningly, I can’t remember what caused it. I’ll see if I can look it up.

Comment: @Robert ok but how can i fix the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, all you need to do is add this to your css:

```
#footer-widgets { overflow: hidden; }
```

The cause might be an incorrect float/clearing, it definitely occurs in the div#footer-widgets, if you set it to display: none; the problem disappears ;)

Comment: By the way, I recommend using IE8 in compatibility view (renders page like IE7 does) because you can use the IE Developer Toolbar and analyze your code step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably due to the Microsoft Internet Explorer box model where measurements apply to the inner content rather than the outter dimensions of the html element.

Comment: At the risk of looking stupid given that I haven’t figured out what the problem is, it’s definitely not a box model thing. The HTML of the page should put IE7 is Standards Mode, and IE7 doesn’t have the old Microsoft box model.

Comment: The page listed by faressoft has a transitional doctype, which is not a strict and hence the microsoft box model.